# "replace into" ONLY if new record has a newest timetamp

Tags: mysql

Simply put, I have a MySQL table with 2 fields (idDevice and timestampReported).

Currently I do this to insert a record:

```
replace into example_lastevent
    SET
    timestampReported =     1523395565, -- april 10 2017
    idDevice=3
```

What I'm trying to do now is modifying this query, so it doesn't update if the previous record has a higher (more recent) timestamp. I tried the following doesn't work

```
replace into example_lastevent
SET
timestampReported = if(timestampReported > 123456, timestampReported,123456) -- 02 Jan 1970 (SHOULD NOT BE EXECUTED)
idDevice=3
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (not tested):

```
INSERT INTO example_lastevent
  SET timestampReported = 1523395565, idDevice=3
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  timestampReported = GREATEST(timestampReported, VALUES(timestampReported));
```

I assume idDevice is a unique key of the table. There's no reason to set that in the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause, since it's bound to be identical.

If you have additional columns, use a CASE:

```
INSERT INTO example_lastevent
  SET timestampReported = 1523395565, otherColumn='ABC123', idDevice=3
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  timestampReported = GREATEST(timestampReported, VALUES(timestampReported)),
  otherColumn = CASE WHEN timestampReported < VALUES(timestampReported) 
                     THEN VALUES(otherColumn) ELSE otherColumn END;
```

Read more:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: Thanks!, that did it, with a little tweaking: the other columns need to be evaluated before timestampReported, otherwise (i assume) it evaluates to the newly set timestamp. so the query goes:
INSERT INTO example_lastevent
  SET timestampReported = 10, descr='Othercolumn', idDevice=30

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

descr= CASE WHEN timestampReported < VALUES(timestampReported) 
                    THEN VALUES(descr) ELSE descr END,
-- ANY OTHER COLUMN IN THE TABLE GOES HERE..
-- Lastly evaluate timestampReported
  timestampReported = GREATEST(timestampReported, VALUES(timestampReported));

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes total sense to evaluate the timestamp last. Good catch.